# How to match stream data through websocket with their respective senders at other end terminal

Tags: javascript, json, html, websocket

On one side of the websocket pipeline I let users sending data in a json format. Each json data frame contains the user’s identity and message. Each user can send message as much as they want to.

In my recent experiment, I set 10 users sending message automatically every 1 seconds. Among these users I pick up five at random at the other end.

Now that I have five window blocks that given to each users I picked up. I want to put all receiving messages into the block that belongs to their respective senders.

How do I do that?

Thank you and hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Is it so, that you want to group the message stream into six categories: user1msg, user2msg, ..., user5msg, the rest??

Comment: Yes, there is no problem if there is only one user at the time. I've created an array and fill it with users' id with a .push() function, but that would only add up data infinitely.

Comment: sorry, I am afraid I do not get it. When should it stop / what you really want to do with these messages?

Comment: Well, I think I'm trying to do something node.js does in the server but on the browser instead. In node.js you send data to server, node recognizes who send it and pass data through accordingly. How do I do something like that on the browser (Chrome) side. That's the point.